# What's the matter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing some ex from book.
Such an example:

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, pay):
        self.name=name
        self.pay=pay
    def lastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.pay*=(1.0+percent)
```

Here is what I get when use IDLE:

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, pay):
        self.name=name
        self.pay=pay
        def lastName(self):
            return self.name.split()[-1]
        def giveRaise(self, percent):
            self.pay*=(1.0+percent)
```

As you can see `def` moves more right in my case. And later when I add `bob=Worker('Bob Smith', 50000)`, and try to get `bob.lastName()` I get a mistake. But if I copy the first example, where `def` is under `class` it works. 
I don't know how to make `def` be under `class` please help!

Comment: Can you please format your code according to the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's clear what you're asking. It seems like you just need to use the delete key to move the indent back to the place you want it.

Comment: Please reword your question. How will anyone find that? Questions should be useful to others

Comment: (Guessing [roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53694374/#comment94244292_53694374) suggested re-titling your question.) `As you can see def moves more right in my case` all I can see is an additional level of indentation. I can't see anything *move*. Is IDLE in `when [I use an?] IDLE` a typo for *IDE*?

Comment: IDLE is integrated development and learning environment for python. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is very important in python. In other languages like C, JAVA we use braces to bound code belonging to a function or a class. In python there are no braces.
In python, if one method of class has indentation of 4 spaces, all other methods should have indentation of exactly 4 spaces.
In your code written to IDLE, indentation is incorrect for `lastName` and `giveRaise` which are class methods and should have same indentation as `__init__`

**INCORRECT INDENTATION**

```
 class Worker:
        def __init__(self, name, pay):

            def lastName(self):

            def giveRaise(self, percent):
```

**CORRECT INDENTATION**

```
 class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, pay):
        pass          
    def lastName(self):
        pass
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        pass
```

Comment: explaination for downvote please. It helps me answer correctly next time.